# Entity Framework (Database first) - Incluir DataAnnotations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dataannotations, database-first

Vi em um link da MS que é possível criar uma classe partial e uma outra de Metadata para incluir DataAnnotations em propriedades criadas pelo Entity Framework (database first). Pois bem, fiz conforme está no exemplo, mas a aplicação apresenta um erro:

> O tipo de metadados associado ao tipo 'Context.CONTEUDO' contém as seguintes propriedades ou campos desconhecidos: CONTEUDO. Verifique se os nomes desses membros correspondem aos nomes das propriedades no tipo principal.

Vou mandar o código das 3 classes (gerada pelo EF, metadata e partial):

```
// EF scaffolding
namespace Context
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class CONTEUDO
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public CONTEUDO()
        {
            this.CONTEUDOS = new HashSet<CONTEUDO>();
            this.CONTEUDO_ANEXO = new HashSet<CONTEUDO_ANEXO>();
            this.CONTEUDO_PERMISSOES = new HashSet<CONTEUDO_PERMISSOES>();
        }

        public int COD_CONTEUDO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> COD_CONTEUDO_PAI { get; set; }
        public int COD_EBOOK { get; set; }
        public string TITULO { get; set; }
        public string TEXTO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CRIADO_EM { get; set; }
        public int CRIADO_POR { get; set; }
        public System.Guid UNIQUE_ID { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CONTEUDO> CONTEUDOS { get; set; }
        public virtual CONTEUDO CONTEUDO_PAI { get; set; }
        public virtual USUARIO USUARIO { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CONTEUDO_ANEXO> CONTEUDO_ANEXO { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CONTEUDO_PERMISSOES> CONTEUDO_PERMISSOES { get; set; }
        public virtual EBOOK EBOOK { get; set; }
    }
}

// Metadata
namespace Context
{
    public class ConteudoMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        [Range(1, 999999)]
        [Display(Name = "Ebook")]
        public int COD_EBOOK;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Título")]
        public string TITULO;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Conteúdo")]
        public string CONTEUDO;
    }
}

// Partial com MetadataType attribute
namespace Context
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ConteudoMetadata))]
    public partial class CONTEUDO
    {
    }
}
```

Está tudo no mesmo namespace, pra não ter problema, mas não funciona.

Comment: CONTEUDOS.CONTEUDO ??? ou só CONTEUDOS em lugar de CONTEUDO veja ´erro

Comment: Conteudos é uma lista de conteúdos que possuem o conteúdo em questão como "pai". O nome da entidade é CONTEUDO mesmo.